# Javascript jquery strange error

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "textman.php",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#textbaz').append(data);
      var file = data.split(" ");
      var set = 0;
      console.log(file);
      $('#textbaz').append("<br><input id='textbox' type='text' placeholder='Type it man, your on the clock!'>");
    }
  });
  $("#textbox").keypress(function() {
  console.log($("#textbox").val());
});
  return false;
})
```

Problem is, it just doesnt console log the value of #textbox. No matter what i type in there, it has no effect D:

Comment: _it just doesnt console log the value of #textbox_ This is not a real error and it's not strange.

Comment: @undefined — No, but it is a problem. (And this problem doesn't cause any error messages to be reported).

Comment: A bigger problem is the nearly infinite permutations of this question on SO. Surely this is a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous. You're binding a `keypress` listener to `#textbox` before it exists in the DOM. In the line `$("#textbox").keypress(...`, the result of `$('#textbox')` will be an empty object, and so no element will have a binder registered.

You need to use delegated events (using `.on`):

```
$('#textbaz').on('keypress', '#textbox', function() { ... });
```

... which only requires that `#textbaz` is available at the time of the call, or register the event in the AJAX callback:

```
success: function(data) {
  ...
  $('#textbaz').append("<br><input id='textbox' type='text' placeholder='Type it man, your on the clock!'>");
  $('#textbox').keypress(function() { ... });
}
```

... which ensures that the call to `.keypress` will be made after `#textbaz` has been appended with the textbox, and hence after `#textbox` has been created.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -  (*event delegation for dynamically created element's with `.on()`*)

```
$('#textbaz').on('keypress',"#textbox",function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**event delegation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added element:

```
$('#textbaz').on("keypress", '#textbox', function () {
    console.log($("#textbox").val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code sends an HTTP request and then binds an event handler to all instances of `#textbox`. Sometime later the HTTP response will arrive and the `success` handler will create `#textbox`.

Move the logic for binding the event handler into the `success` handler.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax is an async call, so `$("#textbox").keypress()` will be most likely executed before you attached the html in your success function. Move $("#textbox").keypress directly after your append() call within the success function and it should work.

Alternately you can use

```
.on('keypress', 'selector', function($element) {/*code*/});
```

for dynamically added elements.